# Regression to find formulas from dataset (from an RPG game - Warspear Online)

Tags: regression

I'm looking for a formulas from an RPG game, to simplify the designation of the elements I used full names instead conventional letters.

> How the system in game was designed? Are there any dependencies here?

Here is the code that you can paste into the sheet in Excel:

$\begin{matrix}
\textrm{Level}& \textrm{Staff} & \textrm{Two-Handed Sword} & \textrm{One-Handed Sword}& \textrm{Bow}\\\hline
1  & 29 & ? & 41 & 57\\
2  & 33 & 74 & 46 & 64\\
3  & 37 & 83 & 52& 72\\
4  & 41 & 92 & 57& 80\\
5  & 46 & 101 & 63& 88\\
6  & 50 & 111 & 69& 97\\
7  & 55 & 121 & 76& 106\\
8  & 60 & 132 & 82& 115\\
9  & 65 & 143 & 89& 125\\
10 & 70 & 154 & 96& 135\\
11 & 75 & 166 & 104& 145\\
12 & 81 & 178 & 111& 155\\
13 & 86 & 190 & 119& 166\\
14 & 92 & 203 & 127& 177\\
15 & 98 & 216 & 135& 189\\
16 & 104& 229 & 143& 201\\
17 & 111& 243 & 152& 213\\
18 & 117& 257& 161& 225\\
19 & 124& 272 & 170& 238\\
20 & 131& 287 & 179& 251\\
21 & 137& 302 & 189& 264\\
22 & 145& 318 & 199& 278\\
23 & 152& 334 & 209& 292\\
24 & 159&    & & \\
25 & 167&    & & \\
26 & 175&    & & \\
27 & 183&    & & \\
28 & 191&    & & \\
29 & 199&    & & 
\end{matrix}$

What is the value for Two-handed Sword on the 1 (first) level? Because I do not know this value.

> And why if I divide e.g Staff/Two-handed Sword (I always get the result 0.4, rounded) or Staff/One-haned Sword (the result 0.7) or One-haned Sword/Two-handed Sword (the result 0.6)?
>
> Whether are the numbers accidental or here is any formula?

---

[here is values in excel with the result of division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exS0A.png)

I will expand the question if necessary or missing the information you need.

**Main questions:**

1. What is the value for Two-handed Sword on the 1 (first) level?
2. Formulas for: Staff, Two-handed Sword, One-handed sword (so that
   higher levels can be calculated e.g 30,31,32 level etc)
3. Other mathematical formulas

Comment: You need to clarify what you ant. Can you clearly write your questions so that we know what to answer?

Comment: This is completely irrelevant but may I ask out of interest -- what game is this from?

Comment: Warspear Online, I used this site [calculator](https://wsdb.xyz/calc/en)

Comment: purple is 0, blue is -1, green is -2, orange is +6 and grey i don't understand how work if you @Jack Crawford are interested in, in example "purple" staff level 4 (41) is equal "green" staff  level 6, somebody who is interesed can check this calculator,  I'm curious how this game was being constructed

Comment: If I didn't have exams over the next few days I'd probably give it a deeper look. Don't forget to up-vote or accept my answer if you're satisfied with it, btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [the same method as I did in the answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3251672/675062), I ran a regression on these data in Excel. As it happens, each of these were quadratic this time, too. Here's what I found.

1. In particular, the value for Two-Handed Swords at level $n=1$ is $66$.
2. - The formula for Staff based on Level ($n$) is: $0.0814n^2 + 3.6298n +
        25.44$.
   - The formula for Two-Handed Swords based on Level ($n$) is: $ 0.1829
        n^2 + 7.7971 n  + 57.7872$.
   - The formula for One-Handed Swords based on Level ($n$) is: $0.1148n^2
        + 4.8796n + 35.901 $.

   As with last time, the output of these functions must be rounded to the nearest integer.
3. The numbers you get by dividing the two are largely accidental; well, they're basically exactly what you'd expect when you divide two quadratics. But there's nothing particularly special about them.

Good luck with the game!

Comment: Can you explain Two-Handed Swords formula? I recived y = 0,1826x2 + 8,1707x + 65,721 (and I do not know how to start with 2 in Excel, can you help?)

Comment: That's a good question -- I actually just got the formula the regular way and translated the function over a unit by $x=n+1$, but I just tested and you can use this trick instead: (https://superuser.com/a/523925/1038311). Basically, select the two columns (just the data you have, so start at $n=2$) and make it a *scatter-plot*. Then select the scatterplot, go to "change chart type", and *then* change it to a line graph and it will start correctly with the $x$ value at $2$ and will give you the correct trend-line. I don't know why Excel doesn't do this automatically, but oh well.

Comment: *I meant $x=n-1$. But using the formula you found, you can always achieve (approximately) the same result as I got by doing this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand++0.1826(n-1)%5E2+%2B+8.1707(n-1)+%2B+65.721

Comment: `y = 0,1826x2 + 7,8055x + 57,733` I do not understand why it was different to me than you but it does not matter (maybe I did wrong the steps you gave), I will wait until tomorrow and mark it as resolved if no one answers

Comment: @poszkodowany It’s just a numerical rounding error; they’re the same up to like two decimal places!

Answer (score 0):

It's clear from the nicely labeled calculations you made that the three columns for staff and one and two handed swords are proportional. So whenever you know any one of the three values at a level you can find the other two by multiplying or dividing by the right constants.

The colored coincidences are just coincidences.